# Проблемные символы в патерне preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Использую такой код:

```
   foreach ($propertyValues as $value) {
                if($value) {
                    $pattern = preg_quote('/'.$value.'/u');
                    $source = preg_replace($pattern, '', $source, 1);
                }
            }
```

Он рабочий, но иногда вылезают не совсем понятные Warning:

```
При $pattern = '/107/105/u';
Вылезает Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '1'

При $pattern = "/TL/TT/u";
Вылезает Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'T'
```

Почему так? Как убрать варнинги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_quote` нужно применить к переменной, а не ко всему регулярному выражению. К тому же, так как вы решили использовать знак косой черты в качестве разделителя, его надо передать как второй аргумент в эту функцию:

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($value, '/') . '/u';
$source = preg_replace($pattern, '', $source, 1);
```